# How to find all text blob fields in a Firebird database

Tags: sql, metadata, firebird

If I want to find the table name and column name of all columns in a Firebird database whose type is `BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT`, what would be the correct metadata query to return this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT
  rf.rdb$relation_name,
  rf.rdb$field_name
FROM
  rdb$relation_fields rf JOIN rdb$fields f
    ON rf.rdb$field_source = f.rdb$field_name
WHERE
  f.rdb$field_type = 261 AND f.rdb$field_sub_type = 1
```

list of possible rdb$field_sub_type codes you can find [here](http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/db/interbase/using_interbase_system_tables/using_interbase_system_tables.html).

Comment: You can also find a list of (standard) types and sub-types in the system table `RDB$TYPES` (eg using: `SELECT a.RDB$FIELD_NAME, a.RDB$TYPE, a.RDB$TYPE_NAME FROM RDB$TYPES a WHERE RDB$FIELD_NAME IN ('RDB$FIELD_TYPE', 'RDB$FIELD_SUB_TYPE')`